# Loop through dictionary in Logramm

Tags: loops, dictionary, foreach, logramm

In the past couple of days I've been trying [Logramm](https://github.com/drkameleon/logramm) and find it rather easy.

However, I can't wrap my head around dictionaries and how to create a loop.

I have created a test dictionary :

```
member = [ 
     .id                : 0,
     .username          : "derek.almond",
     .email             : "derek.almond@mail.com",
     .registrationDate  : "09/12/2014",
     .privileges        : 1
];
```

I then tried looping through it like this :

```
@ info -> member: out info;
```

But all it prints out is a list of the keys (`id`,`username` and so on).

How can I get the objects as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*OK, I can't tell how happy I am for seeing a question in SO about Logramm, my very own brain child :-)*

So, let me help you...

Looping this way you mentioned, actually just gets the keys/indexes. You were right.

So, you could access the object by using the `key` as an index, in the `member` dictionary :

```
@ info -> member: out info + " = " + member[info];
```

---

However, a smoother, more logramm-friendly way of looping through dictionaries is :

```
@ key, value -> member : out key + " = " + value;
```

or using variable injection in the string:

```
@ key, value -> member : out "{:key} = {:value}";
```

---

Good luck with your experiments, and do ask if anything comes up! :-)

Answer (score 4):

I usually do it the `key,value` way.

Here's the code as it should look like:

```
member = 
[ 
     .id                : 0,
     .username          : "derek.almond",
     .email             : "derek.almond@mail.com",
     .registrationDate  : "09/12/2014",
     .privileges        : 1
];

@ key,value -> member: 
{
   out "{:key} = {:value}";
}
```